# Use of 'where' and grammar check

Tags: grammar, usage

> In Shane Koyzcan’s poem “Instructions for a Bad Day,” the author expresses an optimistic attitude towards life **where** he encourages us to forget the burden of the past, to live in the present with hope, to carry on our lives with courage, and to learn to express our lives.

Is where used properly in this sentence?

Do you find anything in this sentence awkward?

Comment: I rolled this question back. Please do not add an additional question to an existig post, unless it serves to help understand the original question. Use a separate post to ask an additional question, please.

Comment: Not now that you have edited the question by deleting the second part of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is used correctly, the sentence isn't awkward although it is very long. *Where* in this case is used to demonstrate/explain in more detail *how* the author expresses an optimistic attitude.

> In Shane Koyzcan’s poem “Instructions for a Bad Day,” the author expresses an optimistic attitude towards life where he encourages us to forget the burden of the past

can be written as:

> In Shane Koyzcan’s poem “Instructions for a Bad Day,” the author expresses an optimistic attitude towards life. He does this by encouraging us to forget the burden of the past

A shorter example would be:

> The man talked about different cats, where he discussed their colour and size.

He talks about different cats, and in more detail, he discusses their colour and size.

To answer your other question:

> I understand the author‘s worry, confusion, and question about the purpose of life, to which I have the same feeling.

You have used *to which* correctly. However I would suggest making *question* plural (*questions*) because it is not a specific single question, but an attitude that encompasses a range of questions. I would also change *feeling* to *feelings* for the same reason, that the author has many feelings about the situation, rather than one specific feeling.

Comment: What about this sentence? Is "which" used correctly here?  and is this sentence awkward?                         I understand the author‘s worry, confusion, and question about the purpose of life, to which I have the same feeling.           thank you very much

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your other question

Comment: @Sonni The final paragraph seems to be a tad misleading - "to" is an incorrect preposition here - if it matters at all once the question was edited.